# Windows BATCH "Can't Find the File Path"

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-prompt

So I was wanting to create a small batch file which runs a command line dialogue and launches various programs when my computer starts up.  More for fun then practical uses really.  My problem is that windows doesn't seem to be able to find some files despite my opening the file path in command prompt itself and copying the file path.  It just gives me a "The system cannot find the file specified error."

Here's the relevant code for the batch file now edited for better readability (sorry about that):

```
//Works
start "" "C:\Program Files\Rainmeter\Rainmeter.exe"

//Also works
"G:\Steam\Steam.exe"

//Everything below this fails
"C:\Program Files(x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"
"C:\Program Files(x86)\Razer\Synapse\RzSynapse.exe"
"C:\Program Files(x86)\eclipse\eclipse.exe"
"G:\Steam\steamapps\common\AdVentureCapitalist\adventure-capitalist.exe"
```

The first two files, rainmeter and steam, open fine, but everything past that fails.  I've tried using both "Filepath" and start "" "Filepath", but neither seems to work. despite both working in the code above.

And, just to clarify, I have double and triple checked the file paths to make sure I didn't get something wrong, but it's just not working.

Thanks for any assistance that can be provided.

Comment: FWIW, on my machine there is a space between the 's' of "Files" and the opening parenthesis in "(x86)" in "Program Files (x86)", but I don't see that in your samples. Are you sure it's correct?

Comment: Same here, The standard path should be "Program Files (x86)" on most Englisch machines, except you manually changed the default name.
And, please, if it is just for fun: Remove the unnecessary code. It is no fun to filter out the 6 relevant lines from 30 lines. ;)

Comment: @azt My apologies for that, I have thus fixed it.

Comment: *sigh* I feel stupid now.  Thanks, there is in fact a space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can provide which ones doesn't open it would be great.

```
"C:\Program Files(x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"
```

Just like how people mentioned in your post comment there should be a space in between Program Files and (x86)

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"
```

Feel free to make use of env variables.

```
%programfiles% ==> C:\Program Files
%programfiles(x86)% ==> C:\Program Files (x86)
"%programfiles(x86)%\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"
```

Comment: "The first two files, rainmeter and steam, open fine, but everything past that fails. I've tried using both "Filepath" and start "" "Filepath", but neither seems to work. despite both working in the code above."   That's what I wrote above.  But, I've edited it to clarify.

Comment: Does it work now or do you need further assistant. No need to feel dumb since it happens to all of us lol. Sometime I try to debug something simple for like 2 hrs staright when I just needed to rest a bit and come back to realize a simple mistake I made :(

Comment: Yes, it works now, sorry I didn't clarify that.  Thanks again :D

Comment: I have the same problem but it didnt solve my issue. I supposed to read file using batch script. When above method is used it gives error like this, 

%programfiles% ==> C:\Program Files
The system cannot find the file C:\Program.

%programfiles% ==> C:\\"Program Files"
The system cannot find the file C:\\"Program Files"